# Continuity of a function on the ring of formal power series, with a metric defined.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $E$ be the ring of formal power series over a field $K$. Consider $S,\ T \in E$. Define a metric $d$ on $E$ by $d(S,T)=0\  $ if $S=T$ and $a^{(-k)}$ for $k=\mathrm{order}(S-T)$, where $a>1$ is fixed. Show that the maps $(S,T)\rightarrow S+T$,  $(S,T)\rightarrow ST$ from $E\times E \rightarrow E $ are continuous with respect to the induced metric topology. Is the derivative map $S \rightarrow S' $ continuous?

I know that I am probably supposed to show that the pre-image of every open set in the target space is open, but I don't even know how to define open sets on $E\times E$ given a metric on $E$ alone, so I am stuck.

Comment: What you have written does not define a metric. You've left something out.

Comment: The constant $a$ might have been specified, although that does not affect the topology.